# Kivy application crashes on android

Tags: python, android, kivy

I'm trying to create a mobile translator by using kivy. When compiling on windows, the application works correctly. When I try to run on android - it crashes after the loading screen. How can this be fixed?

My code:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import requests

URL_AUTH = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/getLangs?'
URL_TRANSLATE = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate'
KEY = '[API key]'
LANG = 'en-ru'

# --- request translate
auth = requests.post(URL_TRANSLATE, data={'key': KEY, 'text': 'Translate', 'lang': LANG, }).text

# --- App
class translator(App):

    def translate(self, instance):
        # --- request translate
        auth = requests.post(URL_TRANSLATE, data={'key': KEY, 'text': input_text.text, 'lang': LANG, }).text
        print(auth)
        # --- Update text in Label
        self.output_text.text = str(auth)


    def build(self):
        al = AnchorLayout()
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=[0.9, 0.9])
        btn = Button(text='Translate', on_press=self.translate)
        global input_text
        input_text = TextInput(multiline=False, text='Enter text')
        self.output_text = Label(text=auth)

        bl.add_widget(input_text)
        bl.add_widget(self.output_text)
        bl.add_widget(btn)
        al.add_widget(bl)
        return al

if __name__ == '__main__':
    translator().run()
```

UPD: I tried to remove the request from the code and compile. Application started

Comment: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform

Comment: There can be thousands of reasons why it's happening. You should connect your phone to your pc and run buildozer with `buildozer android debug deploy run logcat` command. Then you'll see errors in the console.

Comment: Logs: https://pastebin.com/QdBM36fQ

Comment: I tried to remove the request from the code and compile. Application started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the problem. When compiling into a buildozer, it was required to specify the request in the list of requirements.

```
requirements = python3, kivy, requests
```